# Delay between inputs of same key, but no delays between inputs of different keys SSHKEYBOARD

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using `sshkeyboard` library to read key inputs for my raspberry pi which I connect to via an ssh terminal. I noticed that, when spamming a single key, there seems to be a delay between outputs, but when I spam alternating keys, there are no delays between inputs. Consider this simple example code:

```
from sshkeyboard import listen_keyboard

def onpress(key):
    print("input detected")

listen_keyboard(on_press=onpress)
```

Say I spam the 'a' key maybe 10 times rapidly, on the output i get like maybe 4 or 5 outputs of "input detected"

But when I spam 'a' and 's' alternatively like 10 times each, i get like 20 outputs properly. Is there a way to fix this?

Is there a way to ensure that when I spam 'a' 10 times rapidly, I get 10 outputs? However, if I press 'a' slowly taking time between presses, I get the same number of outputs for the same number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Apparently there was a parameter called `delay_second_char` which had a default value of 0.75s and this was the reason why spamming a single character wasn't exactly working.

Hence the following code implementation fixed my issue:

```
from sshkeyboard import listen_keyboard

def on_press(key):
    print("Input detected")

listen_keyboard(on_press=on_press, delay_second_char = 0.05)
```